# forms with nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-attributes

I am using some tutorial to build some complex forms with nested attributes(`project` model and its nests attribute `tags`). The problem is tag. I have those inputs :

```
<input id="project_title" name="project[title]" type="text">
```

and

```
<input id="project_tags_attributes_1383080749618_pill" name="project[tags_attributes][1383080749618][pill]" type="text" placeholder="add a tag" style="display: none;">
```

but no tag attribute is set when submitting the form. I have in my log Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4wly3xgZ3ge6pEc8pJAV0XPGbex0WJKoaQ8lVaoDNNA=", "project"=>{"title"=>"some_project", "tags_attributes"=>{"1383080749618"=>{"pill"=>""}}, "description"=>"descriptor"}, "commit"=>"Create project"}
```

What is weird is that when I check the pill's tag attribute value in my chrome console, just before submitting, I get a correct non null value... How can it be

Comment: are you using rails 4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also ran into that kind of issue. Check if you don't have an unpermitted hash in your logs. If so, set in your project controller :

```
def project_params
  params.require(:dee).permit(:title, :description, tags_attributes: [:pill])
end
```